# dyanamic table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[see jsbin](http://jsbin.com/unaqel/12/edit#javascript,html,live)
if u seen my jsbin then i have two table hardcode table and dynamic table.
i have to create dyanamic table exactly like hardcode table.
i have a problem in hour coloumn how do i loop through table to exactly create hour coloumn like hardcode table.

```
for (var i = 1; i < parseFloat(timeSlot); i++)
            {
                row = tableAppointment.insertRow(i);
                cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                cell1.className += 'csstablelisttd';
                cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell2.className += 'csstablelisttd';
                cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                cell3.className += 'csstablelisttd';
                cell1.innerHTML = startTime;                
                cell2.innerHTML = parseFloat(constMinutes);
                constMinutes = parseFloat(constMinutes + 15);
                if (constMinutes == "60")
                {
                    constMinutes = 0;
                }
            }
```

Comment: only problem in hour colomn remning all looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like [this](http://jsbin.com/uvegiy/edit#javascript,html,live)?

```
        for (var i = 1; i < parseFloat(timeSlot); i++)
        {
            row = tableAppointment.insertRow(i);
            cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.className += 'csstablelisttd';
            cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.className += 'csstablelisttd';
            cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.className += 'csstablelisttd';

            if (constMinutes === 0) {
              cell1.innerHTML=startTimeHour++ + ":00" + startTimeAMPM;
            }   

            cell2.innerHTML = parseFloat(constMinutes);
            constMinutes = parseFloat(constMinutes + 15);
            if (constMinutes == "60")
            {
                constMinutes = 0;
            }
        }
```

I've modified the lines where it sets the `cell1.innerHTML`

```
            if (constMinutes === 0) {
              cell1.innerHTML=startTimeHour++ + ":00" + startTimeAMPM;
            }
```

EDIT:

To the proper AM or PM, I set up an integer that increments and uses the modulus operator.  This way it will only ever be 0 or 1 as it increments.  I increment it every time we hit 12.  It then grabs the text from an array (either AMPM[0] or AMPM[1]).

```
        cellAMPM = 0;
        AMPM = ["AM","PM"];

...

            if (constMinutes === 0) {

              if (startTimeHour === 12) cellAMPM++;
              cell1.innerHTML= startTimeHour + ":00" + AMPM[cellAMPM%2];

              startTimeHour = Number(startTimeHour) % 12 + 1;

            }
```

Comment: how to show 12 pm afterwards row if i change var startTime = "08:00 AM";var endTime = "11:00 PM";

Comment: @Nikhil sorry about that.  It was late last night. :P  Hopefully my edit clears things up.

Comment: Hi joseph i have to add span tag at third cell of every row how can i do that

Comment: @Nikhil Well, it's certainly possible and a lot of people on here could help you with that, but I would suggest trying a few things and then making a new question for it.  We try to keep one topic per question posted.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/unaqel/20/edit#javascript,html,live

make use of Date object, it will reduce your code significantly

Comment: i have to add span tag at third cell of every row how can i do that in javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
if (constMinutes === 0)
                {
                    cell1.innerHTML = startTimeHour++ + ":00" + startTimeAMPM;
                    if (startTimeHour >= 12)
                    {
                        cell1.innerHTML = startTimeHour + ":00" + endTimeAMPM;              
                    }           
                }
```